# How I can extract data from R plot?

Tags: r, plot, knime

As it’s writing on title, I would like to extract a specific data from R plot.

On my program, I use the qcc function with control chart R (It’s Quality Control).

```
#Background color
qcc.options(bg.margin = "white", bg.figure = "gray95")

#R graph ranges of a continuous process variable
qcc(data = Test,
    type = "R",
    sizes = 5,
    title = "Sample R Chart Title",
    digits = 2,
    plot = TRUE)
```

And I obtained this R plot:

[image: Rplot control chart R]

I would like to extract the point which is out of control and the data below the plot.

Can you help me?

Thank you for your answers.

For information :
table:

Day    |Temperature
 -------|---------------
    1   |85
    2   |85
    3   |88
    4   |83
    5   |89
    6   |90
    7   |81
    8   |82
    9   |65
    10  |300

Comment: use subset in data so you can extract the data point

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the `Test` data frame? For example, to provide the first 10 rows, paste into your question the output of `dput(Test[1:10, ])`.

Comment: You don't need to extract data from a plot. You need to extract an outlier from your `Test` data now that your plot has shown it to you.

Comment: I understand but I use QCC fonction which do calculate and give me a plot directly. And i would like to extract some data like UCL, LCL, Center, ect that the plot give.

Comment: they explain how to "remove out-of-control points" in the documentation   https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qcc/qcc.pdf

Comment: this document don't help me to extract the data out of control limit. See : `# remove out-of-control points (see help(orangejuice) for the reasons)
inc <- setdiff(which(trial), c(15,23))
q1 <- qcc(D[inc], sizes=size[inc], type="p")
qcc(D[inc], sizes=size[inc], type="p", newdata=D[!trial], newsizes=size[!trial])
detach(orangejuice)`